# Redux Update array inside array

Tags: javascript, redux

Currently I have a store state like this:

```js
const initState = [
  devices: {
    id: 0,
    data: []
  }
]
```

I would like to insert a string into the data array. And if the array reaches a certain length, clear it. How can I do that? This is what I have currently but it's not working

```js
return state.map((device) => 
            {
                if (device.instanceId !== action.payload.instanceId)
                {
                    return device;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (device.bytestreamData.length < CACHE_SIZE)
                    {
                        var newArray = [...device.bytestreamData];
                        newArray.push(action.payload.bytestreamData);
                        return newArray;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        var newArray = [...device.bytestreamData];
                        newArray.length = 0;
                        newArray.push(action.payload.bytestreamData);
                        return newArray;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Your initial state is a syntax error. Then on the first if case you return an `object` while on the the other cases you return an array.

Comment: I wrote it that way just to illustrate the structure of the state, not the actual code that's going to be ran

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming you want to add the new string to an empty array when you reach the max-size of the array*

```
  if (device.bytestreamData.length === CACHE_SIZE) {
    var newArray = [];
    newArray.push(action.payload.bytestreamData);
    return newArray;
  } else {
    var newArray = device.bytestreamData.slice();
    newArray.push(action.payload.bytestreamData);
    return newArray;
  }
```